# auth0 user store vs. own user store - how do they work together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-connection, auth0

I'm familiarizing myself with auth0 and setting it up on a rails 6 api only app. I'm planning to have a database around different resources etc. One of these resources is a User resource. This will be used for authentication, authorization, and some user data, followers/following relationships etc.
Auth0 provides their own user store, claims this is the most performant, and probably is the easiest thing to set up cause they do everything for you, storing encrypted passwords etc. I'd love to take advantage of this but I'm wondering about how customizable this auth0 user store is. How easily does it work together with my own database, which would store the other resources like follower/following relationships etc.?
And what if I want to add more custom attributes to the user table?

Users will be a fundamental part of my app and will have complex calculations and actions centered around them. Is the auth0 database suitable for this? Or is it more meant as a simple login store for mostly static websites? Does anybody have experience with this?

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

auth0 provides an authentication mechanism based on the OAuth protocol.

The service allows you to outsource user authentication management from your application. It is based around the OAuth protocol, this is not really different from a classic OAuth integration (like facebook or google sign in).

Following [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/rails/01-login) the simplest way to achieve what your want is to create a `users` table in your database and import information during authentication callback. The `request.env['omniauth.auth']` hash contains all the information about the users who signed in from auth0, including email etc. There's a unique id in that hash that you can user to map the auth0 user to your current database one. If the user does not exist, simply create it.

```rb
# auth hash structure from auth0:
#{
#  :provider => 'auth0',
#  :uid => 'auth0|USER_ID',
#  :info => {
#    :name => 'John Foo',
#    :email => 'johnfoo@example.org',
#    :nickname => 'john',
#    :image => 'https://example.org/john.jpg'
#  },
#  :credentials => {
#    :token => 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
#    :expires_at => 1485373937,
#    :expires => true,
#    :refresh_token => 'REFRESH_TOKEN',
#    :id_token => 'JWT_ID_TOKEN',
#    :token_type => 'bearer',
#  },
#  :extra => {
#    :raw_info => {
#      :email => 'johnfoo@example.org',
#      :email_verified => 'true',
#      :name => 'John Foo',
#      :picture => 'https://example.org/john.jpg',
#      :user_id => 'auth0|USER_ID',
#      :nickname => 'john',
#      :created_at => '2014-07-15T17:19:50.387Z'
#    }
#  }
#}

# app/controllers/auth0_controller.rb

class Auth0Controller < ApplicationController
  def callback
    # This stores all the user information that came from Auth0
    # and the IdP

    # request.env['omniauth.auth'] contains all user data
    auth_data = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    user = User.find_or_create_by(auth0_id: auth_data[:uid]) do |user|
      user.email = auth_data[:info][:email]
      # associate any other data from auth0 you need here
    end

    session[:userinfo] = request.env['omniauth.auth']

    # Redirect to the URL you want after successful auth
    redirect_to '/dashboard'
  end

  def failure
    # show a failure page or redirect to an error page
    @error_msg = request.params['message']
  end
end
```

Since the user information is stored in your session, you can use this data to fetch the current user based on the `uid` you stored. That way you can any information you need in your own `users` table.

Hope this helps !

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're suggesting using BOTH the user store on the auth0 side AND having my own corresponding user table in my database (which could have additional attributes and foreign keys etc.) and kind of linking them together via the auth0_id attribute?

Comment: That's right, this is the only way you will be able to keep flexibility on the data you want to add to your users since I don't think you can add custom attributes or relationships to the user object on the auth0 side !